# Error when trying to Linked Services with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 1 in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi I am trying to create a linked to the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 1 but I am getting an error of "You are not allowed to make changes or publish from 'Data Factory' mode as your factory has GIT enabled."

I believe I edited the Data Factory already to remove the connection to GIT (disable GIT) but it is still not working.

Does anyone else have encounter similar issues before and have tips on how to solve this? Any helps is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As we know,it will cost some time for the disconnect on the Git to take into place. We can refresh the page and try again.
- We also can click the dropdown to check if you have removed the GIT successfully.

1. If successfully deleted, it will disappear from here.
   [image]
2. Else, you can remove the Git repo here:
   [image]

Comment: I do believe I have the Git disconnected. I have a screen of "No Git repository configured" instead the option of "Disconnect" since I already clicked on the "Disconnect" before and it's still not working.

Comment: Actually, it worked now. It just took some time for the disconnect on the Git to take into place. Thanks!

Comment: So the answer is it will cost some time for the disconnect on the Git to take into place? I've updated my answer.  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Comment: Yes, it took a while. I wasn’t watching the clock but after I made the changes, within 10-20 mins or so was still not working. And I tried again the next day then it worked.